# Problem on Electricity (interesting one)

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electricity

So I came up with this interesting problem, and I just would like to know if I solve it properly, and if not: where did I get wrong?

> Suppose that one day, one discovers that Coulomb force is somehow incomplete and there must be another term, a sort of correction, like
>
> $$ F = \frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0} \frac{q_1q_2}{r^2}\left(1 + \frac{\chi e^{-4\pi\beta r}}{r^2}\right)$$
>
> where $\chi \in [0, 1]$ and $\beta \in (0, 1]$.
>
> What are the physical dimensions of $\chi$ and $\beta$?
>
> Can we still define a potential, such that $E = -\nabla V$?
>
> How would Gauß law change?

**Solution**

The first question is trivial: $[\chi] = m^2$ and $[\beta] = m^{-1}$ where $m$ stands for *meters*.

The second question I thought it could be solved in a naive way, simply defining the new potential through $F = qE$ hence

$$E = \frac{F}{q} = \frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0} \frac{Q}{r^2}\left(1 + \frac{\chi e^{-4\pi\beta r}}{r^2}\right)$$

And from here

$$V(r) = -\int E \text{d} r$$

Which for simplicity, in one dimension (r = x) gives (with a basic knowledge of special functions)

$$V(x) = -\frac{Q}{4\pi \epsilon_0}\left(\frac{e^{-4 \pi  \beta  x} \left(32 \pi ^3 \beta ^3 \chi  x^3 e^{4 \pi  \beta  x} \text{Ei}(-4 \pi  x \beta )+\chi +8 \pi ^2 \beta ^2 \chi  x^2+3 x^2 e^{4 \pi  \beta  x}-2 \pi  \beta  \chi  x\right)}{3 x^3}\right)$$

Now I have problems with Gauß law.

If I start from

$$\int E\cdot dA = \frac{Q}{\epsilon_0}$$

for a spherical surface of radius $R$, what I would get at the end, would be the classical Gauß law. Hence it wouldn't change.

But this result shall be wrong, since we also have $E = F/q$ the form of which would be pretty different...

Comment: *What are the physical dimensions of χ and β?* This is something you should be trivially able to answer yourself.  Note also that a force has a *direction* as a well as a magnitude, so you've left that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This interesting.

First, the convention as writing the electric field as the gradient of a scalar potential $\mathbf{E} = -\nabla V$ is a mathematical trick, and is only allowable for the electrostatic case of Faraday-Lenz' law

$$ \nabla \times \mathbf{E} = \frac{\partial\mathbf{B}}{\partial t} = \mathbf{0} \quad (\rm electrostatic\, case).$$

For your corrected electric field, you can show that the curl (in spherical coordinates) is

$$ \nabla \times \mathbf{E} = \frac{1}{r}\hat\phi\left[ 0 - \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}{E}_{\rm corrected}(r)  \right] = \mathbf{0},$$
since $E_{\rm corrected}$ has no $\theta$-dependence. The implication is that the answer is yes - we can still define a scalar potential such that $\mathbf{E} = -\nabla V$. I won't bother to compute that myself, as you seem to have it done yourself. But this does answer the concept of it.

For Gauss' law, I do not think I agree. Traditional Coulomb field can be derived from Gauss' law for a point source as

$$ \oint_\Sigma \mathbf{E}\cdot d\mathbf{a} = \frac{Q}{\epsilon_0},$$

where $\Sigma$ is a closed spherical surface. Since the point charge distributes its field uniformly across the surface, you have

$$E \cdot 4\pi r^2 = \frac{Q}{\epsilon_0};$$

that is,

$$ \mathbf{E} = \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \frac{Q}{r^2}\mathbf{\hat{r}}.$$

So, for a point source, you cannot derive $E_{\rm corrected}$ from Gauss' law. So, you would assume either that $E_{\rm corrected}$ is not uniform from a point source over $\Sigma$; otherwise, I think Gauss' law would require a correction. An obvious one is simply

$$ \oint_\Sigma \mathbf{E}\cdot d\mathbf{a} = \frac{Q}{\epsilon_0}\left(1 + \frac{\chi e^{-4\pi\beta r}}{r^2}\right), $$
but there could be many. However, this seems to really violate the essence of Gauss' law -- that the surface integral has an $r$-dependence.

Comment: That clarified me some doubts thank you so much! But I don't get the last phrase: the surface integral DOES depend on $r$, since we integrate on $r$. Or did I get it  in the wrong sense?

Comment: @Henry Yeah, that wasn't obvious; my apologies. I meant the value of the *entire* surface integral is a function of $r$. The whole point of Gauss' law is that if we know $Q_{\rm enc}$ alone, then we can know the electric flux through the closed surface. But this "corrected" form of Gauss' law would indicate that we need to know something about the geometry of the object in order to know the total flux.